# Scala Macros: Convert/parse a Tree to a Name

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

This is a simplified example but the problem remains the same.

I want to achieve this using macros (scala based pseudocode):

```
(a: Int) => {
  val z = "toShort"
  a.z
}
```

If I reify it, I would obtain something similar to this:

```
Function(
  List(
    ValDef(
      Modifiers(Flag.PARAM),
      newTermName("a"),
      Ident(scala.Int),
      EmptyTree
    )
  ),
  Block(
    List(
      ValDef(
        Modifiers(),
        newTermName("z"),
        TypeTree(),
        Literal(Constant("toShort"))
      )
    ),
    Apply(
      Select(
        Ident(newTermName("a")),
        newTermName("toShort")
      ),
      List()
    )
  )
)
```

I dont know how to access to a value and then use it as a TermName.

I tried replacing `newTermName("toShort")` with `newTermName(c.Expr[String](Select(Ident(newTermName("z")))).splice)` but the compiler doesn't seem to like:

> exception during macro expansion: 
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: the function you're calling has not been spliced by > the compiler.
>   this means there is a cross-stage evaluation involved, and it needs to be invoked explicitly.
>   if you're sure this is not an oversight, add scala-compiler.jar to the classpath,
>   import `scala.tools.reflect.Eval` and call `<your expr>.eval` instead.

I've also tried 'eval' as suggested by compiler: `newTermName(c.eval(c.Expr[String](...))` but neither worked.

How could I convert a tree like `Select(Ident(newTermName("z")))` (which is a access to a value of a local val) to <strike>a Name</strike> a string which can be used as a parameter for `newTermName`? Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

Here the real problem brought to you as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/glerchundi/b5c0fef88fb0bb222fde#file-validation-scala-L196)!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `newTermName("z")` already returns a `Name`. I don't understand what is wrong with that one.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract it from an existing Tree? Like `val Select(Ident(name)) = tree`?

Comment: I want to use the value of `val z` to be the param of `newTermName` method. `Select(Ident(newTermName("z")))` is the access to the value and then: `newTermName("<value of z>")`. So it would be possible to do: `a.toShort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve, and why you are using Trees everywhere. Trees are really low level, hard to use, tricky, and it is very difficult to understand what the code does. Quasiquotes (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/quasiquotes.html) are the way to go indeed and you can use them on scala 2.10.x production release thanks to the macro paradise plugin (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html). The you can simply write `q"(a: Int) => {val z = "toShort"; a.z}"` and you directly get the tree expression you just typed.

To answer your question, the first point is to remember that macros are evaluated at compile time. They therefore can not generate code which depends on a runtime value. This is why the compiler is complaining about your `splice`. But if you pass a value which can be computed at compile time, typically a literal, then you can use eval to get its value within your macro code. Eval does suffer a bug though, as indicated in scaladoc. It should only be called on untyped trees. So the way to call eval on an `s: c.Expr[String]` expression would be `val s2 = c.eval(c.Expr[String](c.resetAllAttrs(c.tree.duplicate)))` which gives you a `String` you can then use normally in your code, for instance `q"(a: Int) => a.${newTermName(s2)}"`.

To put it all together, let's imagine you to create a macro that'll output a string value from an object and one of its `String` field. It'll give something like

```
def attr[A](a: A, field: String): String = macro attrImpl[A]

def attrImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(a: c.Expr[A], field: c.Expr[String]) = {
  import c.universe._

  val s = c.eval(c.Expr[String](c.resetAllAttrs(field.tree.duplicate)))
  c.Expr[String](q"a.${newTermName(s)}")

}
```

REPL session test:

```
scala> object a { val field1 = "field1"; val field2 = "field2" }
defined module a

scala> attr(a, "field1")
res0: String = field1

scala> attr(a, "field2")
res1: String = field2
```

To understand the difference between compile time and runtime, you can meditate about the following result in REPL ;-)

```
scala> val s = "field1"; attr(a, s)
error: exception during macro expansion: 
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed: 

$iw is not an enclosing class
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.throwIfErrors(ToolBoxFactory.scala:311)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:244)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.compile(ToolBoxFactory.scala:408)
    at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl.eval(ToolBoxFactory.scala:411)
    at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Evals$class.eval(Evals.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Context.eval(Context.scala:6)
    at .attrImpl(<console>:14)


scala> val s = "field1"
s: String = field1

scala> attr(a, s)
res3: String = field1
```

Hope it helps ;))

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Probably quasiquotes is the way to go but it is available on scala 2.11 which is not official yet. I've put a.z with z being a value defined inside the function to be available at compile time avoiding runtime values. Could you extend your answer with a possible solution of this example? `c.eval(c.Expr[String](Select(Ident(newTermName("z")))))` does not work :\. Take a look to the gist at line 197.

Comment: You can use macro paradise plugin, which includes quasiquotes, on 2.10.x production release as described in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html

Comment: Thanks again, I thought that they are available just in 2.11... Do you known why `c.Expr[Unit](q"""println("hello world!")""")` just works and `c.Expr[Int => Short](q"""(a: Int) => a.toShort""")` does not? This error was thrown :\ (`scala: Unable to read an event from: rO0ABXNyADlvcmcuamV0YnJhaW5zLmpwcy5pbmNyZW1lbnRhbC... Error: Unknown source file: embeddedFile--QuasiquoteCompat.scala@36a12aaa83f74d5b8ce323d542d159c0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown source file: embeddedFile--QuasiquoteCompat.scala@36a12aaa83f74d5b8ce323d542d159c0`

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem here in a REPL. Maybe this IDE or project config on your side.

Comment: It's something weird, i'm using IntelliJ IDEA with an spec instead of REPL but anyway thanks for your answers, really really helpful!!! :)